# Specifying to contributors what version of go to use in a go project

Tags: go, version, metadata

In node projects, `package.json` lets contributors know what version of node they can use to either consume or contribute to a specific project. Python uses `venv` to control the version used in collaborative development environments, and many other languages have similar constructs as well.

Does go have a standardized process that allows you to do something similar?

Comment: [build contraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571661/exclude-go-source-files-by-architecture-when-compiling), possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571661/exclude-go-source-files-by-architecture-when-compiling

Comment: Also related / possible duplicate of [How do I skip a tests file if it is run on systems with go 1.4 and below?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586850/how-do-i-skip-a-tests-file-if-it-is-run-on-systems-with-go-1-4-and-below/37587547#37587547)

Comment: Please wait for dep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but Go has the 1 promise of compatibility - they try very hard not to break any extant software built on 1.x, even at the expense of leaving an ugly API or unwanted behaviour (though this is rare). This means you don't really have to worry about specifying which version of Go you use. Go 2 is not even on the horizon, so for the foreseeable future, you don't have to worry about this. There are a few new features, but most go users upgrade (because of the stable upgrade path).

https://golang.org/doc/go1compat

Re which dependencies you have, at present the only solution is to put your dependencies into a vendor folder, but I think you were asking about the language specifically.